# Why does VS Code think this Spring Framework import cannot be resolved?

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to run a Java/Maven project that apparently works for others, but VS Code won't run this Spring Boot project because:

> The import `org.springframework.data` cannot be resolved.

`import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository`

However, my POM has the dependency that includes that class:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

And the `spring-boot-starter-parent` the project uses is at v2.7.14.

I have the Java extension pack for VS Code.

I've tried `mvn clean.` There's no "reload project" option as some things have said, but I thought I read that VS Code does that when `pom.xml` changes, so I've tried that.

I'm sure it's something simple I'm not doing right, but I can't for the life of me figure it out.

Comment: Do I understand properly that when you run `mvn clean install` you have SUCCESS, and it's only VS Code which considers the project wrong?

Comment: Yes, the maven build succeeds, but VS code has those linting errors, and doing either right-click on the project > Run, or maven spring-boot:run also results in errors: "The project cannot be built until build path errors are resolved;" "The container Maven:Dependencies references non-existing library..." and a bunch of "Missing artifact..."

Comment: Does VS use the same local Maven repository as your standalone MAven?

Comment: As far as I know, but I'm not sure how to check. I did however flip over to a Windows 11 VM with IntelliJ, and the project built and ran right away there, so it's something with VS code; it's just not giving me clear enough error messages to take action on.

Comment: Try `Ctrl+Shift+P-->Java: Clean Java Language Server Workspace` and then restart vscode.